# How to change the tab bar image using NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a application with custom tab bar, and i can't change the image, the title i can..

```
UIImage* item0image = [[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.iconoTabMoneda1]]
                       imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIImage* item1image = [[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.iconoTabMoneda2]]
                       imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

item0.selectedImage = item0image;
item1.selectedImage = item1image;
```

Comment: Are you working with the asset catalog? Is the image defined correctly for @2x/@3x and non retina? Make sure the produced string is the correct file name (without the suffix). What I guess is happening is that you're trying to instantiate a UIImage with a wrong file name.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the suffix, either ".png" or ".jpeg", whichever it is, to the image name.